# JQuery form is posted on all clicks

Tags: jquery, forms

Well, this is beginner question - every time I click on option or remove button, it posts data. How can I prevent it from happenning? Here is my form and JQuery code.

```
<form method="post" id="saveForm" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>
            <select id="select" name="lang">
                <option> </option>
                <option>one</option>
                <option>two</option>
            </select>
            <label>Category Name</label>
            <input id="inputVal" type="text" name="category" />
            <br/>

        </p>
        <p>
            <button  type="button" class="add" >
                Add fields
            </button>

            <button type="button" class="remove">
                Remove
            </button>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
        </p>

        <label>Image:</label>
        <input type="file" id="image" name="picture" accept="image/*">
    </form>
```

Here is my submittion function. I also have function for .add and .remove buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#saveForm').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var obj = $("#saveForm").serializeObject();
            obj = JSON.stringify(obj);
            alert(obj);
            /*
            $.ajax({
                                type : "POST",
                                url : "@routes.UploadController.uploadView()",
                                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                data : obj,
                                success : function(data) {
                                    alert(data);

                                },
                                error : function(data) {
                                    alert("Oops Something Went Wrong " + data);

                                }
                            });
            */

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
 $('#saveForm').click(function(e) {
```

To:

```
 $('#saveForm').submit(function(e) {
```

Before you had a handler for every time you clicked anywhere in the `form`, with `submit()` it will only submit when you submit the form.

Comment: I had to wait time limit. :)